# how to store Hex data using json in python

Tags: python, json, encryption, hex

I am getting this error when storing data in to a file

> TypeError: b'\x1fa\xec\xb5\xed]k\xaf\x8dzph\xb2\x8d\xcc\x8e' is not
>   JSON serializable

This is the code I am using. But it doesn't seem to be giving the right outcome as the file gets corrupted once the data is stored.

```
    iv = os.urandom (16)
    msg_IV = base64.b64encode(iv)
    padding = u'\u0000'
    file = {"IV": msg_IV,\
        "Padding Character": padding }

    fp = open("local.txt", "w")
    json.dump(file, fp, indent=4)
    fp.close()
```

This small program is supposed to store encrypted variable information and store in a file.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a byte string, and there is no standard way to store raw bytes in a JSON object.

You should instead encode the bytes into base64 and store the base64 string in your JSON object:

```
import base64

b64String = base64.b64encode(myByteString)
```

Comment: @user3686282 Then you are doing something wrong :) Edit your question to include your updated code.

Comment: i have just updated the question if you could check thanks